# Execute Anonymous works with trigger, Test Class Doesn't

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, failing-tests

I have written a trigger that will aggregate into a list all instances of an opportunity picklist on any contact with a (opportunity) contact role relating it to an opportunity. I.E. Contacts A and B have OpportunityContactRoles with opportunity 1, 2, and 3. Opportunity 1.program_type = "hello", Opportunity 2.program_type = "hello", Opportunity 3.program_type = "goodbye." After an insert or update, Contacts A and B should have a field that reads '["hello","goodbye"]'.

I've tried to write a test class for this trigger, but even though I insert the new data and update the opportunity, the field is not populated. However, when I take the same actions through an execute anonymous, the trigger works perfectly. Could someone help me ascertain what I am doing incorrectly?

Trigger code:

```
trigger ProgType on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    //Create contact list
    set<ID> contactIds = new set<ID>();
    //Create opportunity list
    set<ID> oppIds = new set<ID>();
    //Add opportunity IDs to opportunity list for all opportunities that are triggering
    if (Trigger.new != null) {
        for (Opportunity record: trigger.new) {
            if(record.recordtypeid == '012a00000018Esx' || record.recordtypeid == '012300000006GiS' || record.RecordTypeId == '012300000006GiI') {
                oppIDs.add(record.id);
            }
        }
    }
    if (trigger.old != null) {
        for (Opportunity record: trigger.old) {
            if (record.recordtypeid == '012a00000018Esx' || record.recordtypeid == '012300000006GiS' || record.RecordTypeId == '012300000006GiI') {
                oppIds.add(record.id);
            }
        }
    }  
    //below is the code to populate the all program types field on contacts related to this opportunity
    //remove any null values from the Opportunity list   
    oppIds.remove(null);
    //Add all contacts to the Contact list that have a contact role related to an opportunity in the Opportunity list
    for (opportunitycontactrole o: [select contactid from opportunitycontactrole where opportunityid in :oppIds]) {
        contactIds.add(o.contactid);
    }
    //remove any null values from the Contact List
    contactIds.remove(null);
    //create a new list of opportunities
    list<id> newOppIds = new list<id>();
    //populate the new list with all opportunities related to Contacts in the contact list as investor, joint investor, trustee, or account representative
    for (opportunitycontactrole o: [select opportunityid, opportunity.stagename from opportunitycontactrole where contactid in :contactIds and role in ('Investor','Joint Investor','Trustee','Account Representative')]) {
        if (o.Opportunity.stagename=='converted') {
            newOppIds.add(o.OpportunityId);
        }
    }
    //create blank map of contact id and set of program types
    map<Id, Set<String>> programs = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();
    //populate map with contact id and all related program types
    for (Opportunitycontactrole record: [SELECT contactid, opportunity.program_type__c FROM Opportunitycontactrole WHERE opportunityid in :newOppIds]) {
        if (programs.containsKey(record.contactid)) {
            programs.get(record.contactid).add(record.opportunity.program_type__c);
        } else {
            programs.put(record.contactid, new Set<String> { record.opportunity.program_type__c });
        }
    }
    //create blank list of contacts to be updated
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[0];
    //populate list of contacts to be updated
    for (Id contactID: contactIds) {
        contacts.add(new Contact(ID=contactId, All_Program_Types__c = programs.containsKey(contactId)?JSON.serialize(programs.get(contactId)):null));
    }
    update contacts;
}
```

Test Class Code:

```
@istest
public with sharing class TestProgType {

    @isTest static void testProgTypeTrigger(){

        //Test data setup
        //Create contact, opportunity, and opportunity contact role
        contact testcontact = new contact (firstname = 'test', lastname = 'testing', recordtypeid = '01230000000p4Eb');
        opportunity testopp = new opportunity (name='testing',stagename='converted',closedate=date.today(),recordtypeid = '012a00000018Esx');
        testOpp.program_type__c = 'OTO: Twin Cities';
        insert testcontact;
        insert testOpp;
        opportunitycontactrole testRole = new opportunitycontactrole (contactid = testcontact.id, opportunityid = testOpp.id, role = 'Investor',isprimary = TRUE);
        insert testrole;

        system.assert(testcontact.All_Program_Types__c == null);

        //perform test
        testOpp.program_type__c = 'OTO: Denver';
        test.startTest();
        update testOpp;
        test.stopTest();

        //Verify that testcontact now has text

        system.assert(testcontact.All_Program_Types__c != null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Records updated through a DML statement don't automatically show any changes to the caller (except for an ID field being updated on inserts). You must first *query* the data back from the database after performing a DML statement before comparing the value:

```
testContact = [SELECT All_Program_Types__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :testContact.Id];
System.assertNotEquals(null, testContact.All_Program_Types__c);
```

Comment: If I may ask a follow up question: After this test class, I have 96% coverage with the exception of line 44: "programs.get(record.contactid).add(record.opportunity.program_type__c);"

Would I need to insert another opportunity belonging to the same contact in order to test that part of the loop?
-------UPDATE: It worked! :) 100% coverage

Comment: @krewllobster Good. I was going to say that there's a way you can optimize the code to reduce the number of opportunities to 1 (for code coverage), but I found out over the last month or so that it is a pretty severe CPU hit (40-50ms *per record*), so this would indeed be ideal.